# Matrix invertibility in terms of elementary operations

Tags: linear-algebra

There is a theorem that an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if $A$ is row equivalent to $I_n$, and in this case, any sequence of elementary row operations that reduces $A$ to $I_n$ also transforms $I_n$ to $A^{-1}$.

Can anyone shows how the proof is?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? The if and only if part or the elementary row operations part?

Comment: The proof should also be available in any textbook which teaches you what row equivalence is. The proof itself is more or less constructive

Comment: I think the key piece is that performing an elementary row operation (ERO) on $A$ is equivalent to multiplying by an elementary matrix (i.e. a matrix obtained by performing and ERO on the identity matrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show that this is true, use can use the idea of [Elementary Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix).

If you want to perform one of the three elementary row operations on some matrix $M$ (row switching, row adding, or row scaling), this is equivalent to pre-multiplying $M$ by one of three special types of matrices, which I generically denote with $E$.

The result of a series of $n$ row operations on $M$ has the form $E_n E_{n-1} ... E_ 3 E_2 E_1  M$.

Each elementary matrix $E_i$ is invertible, so if $M$ is row equivalent to the identity matrix $I$,

$$I = E_n E_{n-1} ... E_ 3 E_2 E_1  M$$

then the inverse of $M$ has the form,

$$M^{-1} = E_n E_{n-1} ... E_ 3 E_2 E_1$$

So a matrix being invertible and a matrix being row-equivalent to the identity are the same thing.

---

Examples of elementary matrices:

Row-switching matrices are just the identity with the appropriate rows swapped. This matrix swaps rows 2 and 3:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$$

Row-scaling matrices are just the identity with the appropriate row scaled. This matrix scales the second row by 5:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

Row-adding matrices are just the identity with an extra off-diagonal non-zero element $E_{i,j}$ which adds that number times row $j$ to row $i$. This matrix adds -2 times row 3 to row 1:

$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$

It isn't hard to show that each of these matrices is invertible.

Comment: Thanks, but how to proof of transforms In to A−1?

Comment: @Questionsboy You can the equation for $M^{-1}$ and just stick the Identity on the end:  $M^{-1} = E_1^{-1} E_2^{-1} E_3 ^{-1} ... E_{n-1}^{-1} E_n ^{-1} I$.

Comment: Why the M−1=(EnEn−1...E3E2E1)−1=E−11E−12E−13...E−1n−1E−1n?

Comment: @Questionsboy I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you re-phrase your question? I though you were asking me "how does the identity $I$ transform into $M^{-1}$?", but I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: yes, but I believe I understand now. Thanks eigenchris

Comment: @Questionsboy I just noticed a mistake in my answer. I should have written $M^{-1} = E_n E_{n-1} ... E_ 3 E_2 E_1$. Maybe this is what you were referring to? Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Gauss-Jordan elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination) method and it is a simple consequence  of row-echelon form reduction method to solve a linear system.. For a proof you can see: [Proof of inverse matrices, with method of Gauss / Jordan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389686/proof-of-inverse-matrices-with-method-of-gauss-jordan)